# Oracle Apex Page Process Success Message - Page Fields

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Apex 4.2.  Is it possible to include a page field name in the page Process Success Message or Process Error Message?  I'm looking to include something like: 
Book successfully deleted for: :P281_Title
Also, can I include a hard return after the message so that a subsequent process will have its success message on a new line?
Many Thanks for looking at this.
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up your success message like this:

```
Book successfully deleted for: &P281_TITLE.<br/>
```

I didn't expect the `<br/>` tag to work, but it did when I just tried it in APEX 4.2.

**Note:** you must reference the item name in uppercase with this syntax.

Comment: Hi Tony,  Thanks.  The breaking return (<br/>) worked.  However, I can't get the field data to show up.  I double-checked the spelling of the field.  Sure enough, it's P281_TITLE.  I made sure to reference the field in upper case.  As a matter of fact, I coped line line right from your reply above.  The message I receive is just "Book successfully deleted for:"  No field data and no period.  In order to force an error, I changed the ampersand to a colon and I got the response: "Book successfully deleted for: :P281_TITLE."  Any ideas why &P281_TITLE returns a blank and no period?  Thanks again,

Comment: The value of `&P281_TITLE.` has to have been saved to session state, could that be the problem?

Comment: Hi Tony.  Saving the Session State for the page item worked.  Thanks very much.  BTW, I decided I wanted to pull in multiple page items into the message. However, referencing multiple page items in the process message failed.  So I created a hidden page item, Saved the Session State, and referenced that one hidden page item in the process message.  That also worked fine!  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Also, I had to clear the cache for page 281 in the After Processing / Go To Page branch process.